# jquery pagination for ajax data

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, pagination, elgg

I have having 3 tabs which I have written ajax in click function to get posts.

I have simplified my coding:

in document ready

```
$.ajax({
type : "GET",
url:"xxx",
data:{ method:'wire.get_posts', limit:'10', offset:'0', context:'all' },            
dataType:"json",
success:function(all_data) {
    $("#tabs-1").append(all_element);
}
});
```

And this is my pagination

```
//how much items per page to show
var show_per_page = 2; 
//getting the amount of elements inside content div
var number_of_items = $('#tabs-1').children().size();
//calculate the number of pages we are going to have
var number_of_pages = Math.ceil(number_of_items/show_per_page);

//set the value of our hidden input fields
$('#current_page').val(0);
$('#show_per_page').val(show_per_page);

//now when we got all we need for the navigation let's make it '

/* 
what are we going to have in the navigation?
- link to previous page
- links to specific pages
- link to next page
*/
var navigation_html = '<a class="previous_link"   
href="javascript:previous();">Prev</a>';
var current_link = 0;
while(number_of_pages > current_link){
navigation_html += '<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(' + current_link   

+')" longdesc="' + current_link +'">'+ (current_link + 1) +'</a>';
current_link++;
}
navigation_html += '<a class="next_link" href="javascript:next();">Next</a>';

$('#page_navigation').html(navigation_html);

//add active_page class to the first page link
$('#page_navigation .page_link:first').addClass('active_page');

//hide all the elements inside content div
$('#tabs-1').children().css('display', 'none');

//and show the first n (show_per_page) elements
$('#tabs-1').children().slice(0, show_per_page).css('display', 'block');

//pagination functions
function previous(){

new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) - 1;
//if there is an item before the current active link run the function
if($('.active_page').prev('.page_link').length==true){
go_to_page(new_page);
}

}

function next(){
new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) + 1;
//if there is an item after the current active link run the function
if($('.active_page').next('.page_link').length==true){
go_to_page(new_page);
}

}
function go_to_page(page_num){
//get the number of items shown per page
var show_per_page = parseInt($('#show_per_page').val());

//get the element number where to start the slice from
start_from = page_num * show_per_page;

//get the element number where to end the slice
end_on = start_from + show_per_page;

//hide all children elements of content div, get specific items and show them
$('#tabs-1').children().css('display', 'none').slice(start_from, end_on).css('display', 
'block');

/*get the page link that has longdesc attribute of the current page and add active_page 
class to it
and remove that class from previously active page link*/
$('.page_link[longdesc=' + page_num 
+']').addClass('active_page').siblings('.active_page').removeClass('active_page');

//update the current page input field
$('#current_page').val(page_num);
}
//pagination functions
```

I append html element in ajax success

My pagination is working if it is static content

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a id="ui-id-1" href="#tabs-1">All</a></li>
<li><a id="ui-id-2" href="#tabs-2">Mine</a></li>
<li><a id="ui-id-3" href="#tabs-3">Friends</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1">
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">    
</div>

<div id="tabs-3">
</div>
</div>
<br>

<!-- An empty div which will be populated using jQuery --> 
<div id='page_navigation'></div>
```

Comment: Making a working fiddle would help us help you :p

Comment: when i give static content in my tab-1 div pagination works. but its not wokin when $().append is used in tab-1. My previous,next functions are out side of $doc ready.

Comment: in ajax data i have to change the offset:'0' to offset:'10' in next page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands, it seems that your "pagination code" is not called right after the success of your AJAX call : at the time it's executed, the data has not necessarily been transferred from your server. As a result, it's useless ; meanwhile with static content, the data is already in your `#tabs-1`, thus it works.

As a remind, [AJAX means Asynchronous Javascript and XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

You should then wrap all your pagination code into the `success` method of your ajax call, so it'll paginate only when the data is retrieved.